# plotting normalized auto-correlation using matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have a problem due to plotting auto-correlation. Firstly, x is a vector contains random length observations of light readings. All the values of this x vector ranging from 0 to 250 randomly and collected using the light sensor for a period of 1 minute (60 seconds). I want to compute the auto-correlations between the values for 60 lags as in this equation.

[image]

Then, I want to compute the normalized auto-correlation values using this equation.

[image]

I tried to do this using Matlab code as following, but it not working with me:

Code:

```
[acf,lags,bounds] = autocorr(x,60, []);
```

My output:

[image]

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code you used for plotting and calculating the normalized autocorrelation?

Comment: @hazeiio , unfortunately, I do not have a code, I am looking for a code to represent a normalized auto-correlation function on a vector of random time series values. Could you help me how I can do it using Matlab?